# Increased magnetic field strength from creating a bar magnet from smaller magnets with opposing poles

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I was wondering if the strength of a bar magnet constructed from smaller magnets would increase if the smaller magnets were placed in an arrangement where the poles were opposing each other. I was able to jam 2 rare earth magnets together with opposing poles and measured a higher magnetic flux density with a gaussmeter.

Would there be a higher magnetic flux density from sticking magnets together with opposing polarity than sticking magnets together with non opposing polarity?

Comment: Hi mfade, we need to know a bit more about the situation you're describing to answer this properly - In each situation (1 magnet and 2 magnet), how exactly was the gauss meter positioned, and what axis was it measuring the magnetic field in?

Comment: 2 magnets that were forced together with opposing polls read a higher gauss rating than 2 magnets that were stuck together with non-opposing polls. The gauss measurements were made at 90 degrees (normal) to the magnets in both tests. Measurements were made by moving the gaussmeter in the x direction.